# rails server command not working and no gems on another version of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pik

i'm running rails on a windows 7 machine and am using pik as my RVM.

i have ruby 1.9.3 currently installed but i have a project that requires ruby 1.9.2.

so using pik, i run these commands from `gitbash`:

1. `pik 192`
2. `ruby -v`

> ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

1. `rails server`

> sh.exe": rails: command not found

however, when i use pik 193 i can definitely see the server running. running gem list under pik 192 also does not display any local gems while pik 193 displays a lot of them.

how do i "share" the gems between these 2 version or is there a better option that will be less risky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share gems across installations, you need to install the gems in a common place to the two installations.

By default, Ruby on Windows will install gems inside the directory of Ruby.

You can verify this by doing:

```
gem env gemdir
```

To install in a common place for both interpreters, you will need to set `GEM_HOME` environment variable to a specific directory, like `C:\gems`

```
SET GEM_HOME=C:\gems
gem env gemdir
```

You will also require to add the `bin` directory to the `PATH`:

```
SET PATH=C:\gems\bin;%PATH%
```

That will allow gems executables be available.

However, please note that while Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 state they are compatibles, is might not be true for compiled C extensions that are part of some gems.

Ruby 1.9.3 introduced certain API-level functions that are not available in 1.9.2 and that can cause issues when a 1.9.3-compiled gem is loaded in Ruby 1.9.2

These differences can cause segmentation fault and weird application crashes in some cases.

It is not recommended, so use at your own risk.

Hope that helps.

Comment: is it possible to install gems only for 1.9.2? i tried switching to 1.9.2, running gem install rack. it completed successfully but when i do gem list i get nothing

Comment: what is the output of `gem env` and where is stating the gems are installed? have you checked `gem env gemdir` and also `gem env path` tells you?